# Receiving 'collection' does not exist on type 'HttpsFunction' error with NestJS and Firestore

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, nestjs

I'm trying to connect firestore to a NestJS app in my monorepo and so far when running `firebase serve --only functions` the app works and I'm able to see the welcome message.  However I'm not too clear on how to go about querying data inside the app.

Inside the `index.ts` file I created I exported this constant

```
export const dataApi = functions.region('us-central1')
  .https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    await createFunction(expressServer);
    expressServer(request, response);
  });
```

Seeing that the path to my nest app is `api` I decided to name this constant `dataApi` just to keep things from getting confused.  From here I have absolutely no clue as to what I should be doing inside my services to query data from my database.  The only thing I've been able to think of to try is importing the `dataApi` const into the service and trying this

```
getSampleData(){
    return dataApi.collection('product_index_list').get().then();
  }
```

Of course this function isn't complete as I don't do anything yet with the `then()` method.  But I got the squiggly lines showing there's an error with the code which is the error in the title.  Everything I find about Firestore and NestJs is all about setting it up but never querying data.  Everything I look at in Firestore does things totally different from how it has us set things up for NestJS.  What am I supposed to be doing here to start querying the database?

Comment: I'm totally unclear how you got to the point of trying to query Firestore using your `dataApi` export.  That variable won't help you query Firestore at all.  If you are writing Cloud Functions code in nodejs, you will need a nodejs library to query Firestore.

Comment: For lack of knowing what to do from there that was the only thing I could think of to attempt inside my Nest app.  The handful of tutorials I've come across using these technologies just shows how to get it set up but never demonstrates reading or writing data from the database.  I've come across other tutorials where they show you how to do something like `db.collections('product-list').get().then(...)`  but they never show how or where they define `db` so it connects to the database.

Comment: I installed Firebase into the main folder of my monorepo rather than inside my Nest App because I want to be able to connect another Backend app to it later on figuring that would make it easier so I don't have to install it multiple times, which I assumed I would be able to do but now I'm not so sure.

Comment: The documentation for the Firestore SDK for nodejs will show you how to create `db`.  It will be shown once, and assumed for the rest of the documentation that you know how to do it (no point in repeating it for every code sample).